# How to know in which mode a record is by ClientScript on NetSuite?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

We can use the following UserEventScript code to do detect which mode a record is in:

```
    switch (context.type) {
        case context.UserEventType.CREATE:
            break;
        case context.UserEventType.EDIT:
            break;
        case context.UserEventType.DELETE:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

But do we have any similar way to know that by **ClientScript**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mode the record is in using the `context.mode` of the `pageInit` entry point.

`mode` can be `copy`, `create`, or `edit`.

```
  function pageInit(context) {
            if (context.mode !== 'create')
                return;
// do stuff
            });
        }
```